# Самый быстрый способ конвертации списка кортежей в список именованных кортежей и обратно

Tags: python, python-3.x

Коллеги, дан список кортежей, надо перегнать его в список именованных кортежей. И наоборот.

Метод, который предлагает документация:

```
from collections import namedtuple

Nt = namedtuple('Nt', 'field1 field2 field3')
tuple_list = [(1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9)]

named_tuple_list = list(map(Nt._make, tuple_list))
```

Пробовал через генератор:

```
named_tuple_list = [Nt(*t) for t in tuple_list]
```

Померил время - официальный вариант быстрее.

С обратной конвертацией та же история.

```
new_tuple_list = [tuple(t) for t in named_tuple_list]
```

```
new_tuple_list = list((map(tuple, named_tuple_list)))
```

`map` работает быстрее чем генератор (спасибо @Danis).

Вопрос: `map` - это оптимальный способ с точки зрения скорости исполнения кода?

Comment: а нельзя `list(map(tuple, ...))`?

Comment: @Danis точно! Тупанул, спасибо! Изменил вопрос. Но главный вопрос остается - это оптимальное решение?

Comment: @AlexeyTrukhanov, я думаю, это неоднозначный вопрос. Оптимальное решение не всегда самое быстрое

Comment: @DarkSpace если я не точно описал это в вопросе, то меня как раз интересует однозначный критерий - скорость. То есть вопрос именно в оптимальности с точки зрения скорости выполнения. В данном случае "оптимальность" с точки зрения, например, скорости разработки или удобства чтения кода не является рассматриваемым критерием.

Answer (score 1):

От нечего делать решил сравнить оба метода, которые вы предлагаете. Выбирал руками без всякой автоматизации, но, возможно, попробую написать что-то для отслеживания и сбора данных.

### Изначально вы предлагали два варианта:

- Вариант со списковым включением
- Вариант с list + map

Я подумал и добавил ещё два варианта. От ваших они практически не отличаются. За тем исключением, что `tuple_list` - это кортеж
Сделал это из того соображения, что кортеж занимает меньше места, чем лист. Может быть, это сыграет роль
Пример:

```
a = [1]
b = (1)

print(a.__sizeof__()) # 48
print(b.__sizeof__()) # 28
```

Каждый скрипт запускался обособленно от других. Запускал я 5 раз и результат получился следующий:

[image: Результаты эксперимента]

Код, которым я тестировал:

```
from collections import namedtuple
import time

start = time.time()

for i in range(5000):
    Nt = namedtuple('Nt', 'field1 field2 field3')
    tuple_list = ((1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9))
    named_tuple_list = [Nt(*t) for t in tuple_list]

end = time.time() - start

print('Время выполнения списковое включение + (кортеж) - ', end)

# ---------------------------------------------

start = time.time()

for i in range(5000):
    Nt = namedtuple('Nt', 'field1 field2 field3')
    tuple_list = [(1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9)]
    named_tuple_list = [Nt(*t) for t in tuple_list]

end = time.time() - start

print('Время выполнения списковое включение - ', end)

# ---------------------------------------------


start = time.time()

for i in range(5000):
    Nt = namedtuple('Nt', 'field1 field2 field3')
    tuple_list = [(1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9)]
    named_tuple_list = list(map(Nt._make, tuple_list))

end = time.time() - start

print('Время выполнения list + map - ', end)


# ------------------------------------------


start = time.time()

for i in range(5000):
    Nt = namedtuple('Nt', 'field1 field2 field3')
    tuple_list = ((1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9))
    named_tuple_list = list(map(Nt._make, tuple_list))

end = time.time() - start

print('Время выполнения list + map + кортеж - ', end)
```

Comment: У меня есть два комментария к Вашим измерениям. 1. Изначально нам дан список кортежей. Если говорить о конкретной задаче, то это получение данных из таблицы Postgresql, которые возвращаются как раз в списке кортежей. Поэтому, чтобы измерения, в предложенном Вами варианте кортежа кортежей были "честными", надо внутрь измерений включать еще и изменения типа коллекции со списка на кортеж.

Comment: 2. В том простом случае, который я привел как пример, и у меня результаты были похожи. Но я генерировал рандомный список кортежей из 100_000 кортежей по три элемента от 0 до 500. И гонял конвертацию 100 и 1000 раз. list(map()) однозначно побеждает.

Comment: @AlexeyTrukhanov, я перепроверил и в таком случае вариант list(map) без кортежей будет чуть быстрее, чем с ним (примерно на 1 процент). Разница небольшая, но есть.  Варианты со списковыми включениями отстают по времени процента на 3(без кортежа) и 4 (с кортежем)

Comment: Да, у меня аналогичные результаты.